# C++ открытие файла относительно папки .exe

Tags: c++, файлы, cmd, filestream

Есть консольная программа, например компилятор. В папке с программой есть `config-файлы`. И вот вопрос: как мне открывать этот файл. Полные пути прописать не получится, а если получится - то будет тяжело. А если относительный путь - то он будет относителен той папке, в которой находится пользователь.

Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли открыть файл относительно `exe` файла? Если да - то как?

Или предложите вариант по-лучше, если такой есть.

Comment: Можно [выяснить, какой путь к `exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528298/get-path-of-executable), и относительно него найти `config` файл.

Comment: @IvanDidyk извините, на вопрос, который вы мне скинули ссылку нет правильных ответов. Либо есть, но не кроссплатформенный.

Comment: естественно, что никакого кроссплатформенного ответа тут быть не может

Comment: Нормальный подход — передавать путь к конфигу через командную строку. Типа `program -c /path/to/config`

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev извините, вот допустим интерпритатор python требует такого? Нет. G++? нет. Java? Тоже нет.

Comment: @IvanDidyk а насколько хороший вариант добавить путь в переменную среды?

Comment: Кто мешает использовать относительный путь и преобразовать его в абсолютный, зная папку exe-файла (аргумент `argv[0]` нормально работает по сути везде)...

Comment: @Harry вы вот вроде умный, я вас часто вижу, а даже не знаете что такое `argv[0]`... это то что передается в командную строку. Я могу добавить путь к программе в Path. И я не буду писать полный путь до программы.

Comment: Это зависит от компилятора etc etc. Я написал - "по сути везде", наверняка есть компиляторы, которые поступают не так, как обычно. Но, например, в VC++  это отнюдь не то, что передается в командную строку (но вы вроде умный, так что должны и сами это знать... :)), а именно абсолютный путь к .exe. Если вам очень хочется обмануть программу - наверное, вы сумеете это сделать (не везде... надурите мне VC++ - хочу посмотреть, как это делается...), но тогда зачем спрашивать? Кстати, если вы боитесь `argv[0]` - ну, системное API еще никто не отменял...

Comment: @Harry Что-то вас не в ту сторону понесло. [В документации к vc++ специально весит предупреждение, что не следует закладываться на то, что в `argv[0]` лежит путь к исполняемому файлу](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/main-function-command-line-args?view=vs-2019#command-line-arguments).

Comment: @user7860670 Автор собирается запускать свою программу через CreateProcess с, гм... альтернативно одаренным набором параметров? Или речь идет об обычном запуске из консоли, показанном в копии экрана? Если бы автор написал "я делаю все возможное, чтобы было нельзя получить путь к exe и хочу к нему все равно привязаться" - тогда дело несколько иное, тогда нужно использовать API. *Не преумножайте сущности сверх поставленной задачи*

Comment: Можно. Разбираете PATH, argv[0] и результат getcwd()

Comment: @Harry, это пять! )))

Comment: @user7860670, a `VC++` это `defaut` компилятор такой?

Comment: @Majestio А закладываться, что в argv[0] лежит путь к исполняемому файлу, нельзя и при использовании любого другого компилятора.

Comment: В Стандарте С++ написано "argv[0] ... ... ... представляет имя, используемое для вызова программы, или """. А на практике я еще ни разу не встречал случая, когда в argv[0] была бы пустая строка.

Comment: @Majestio Как видите, там не написано, что это должен быть путь к исполняемому файлу.

Comment: Согласен - я ошибся. И в своем ответе я привел исправленный код.

Comment: @Данил интерпретатор питона, гцц и жаба ищут какой-то конфиг по пути относительно местоположения исполняемого файла?

Comment: ну не в одном же файле эти программы, верно?

Answer (score 1):

> Возможно ли открыть файл относительно exe файла? Если да - то как?

Для `С++17` можно попробовать так:

```
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32) && !defined(__CYGWIN__)
#include <windows.h>
#else
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

std::string GetConfigPath(const char* argv) {
  std::string ret;
  #if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32) && !defined(__CYGWIN__)
  #pragma message("win")
  char *dir = (char*)calloc(32767,sizeof(char));
  if (dir != nullptr) {
    if(GetModuleFileName(nullptr,dir,32767) > 0) ret = dir;
    free(dir);
  }
  #else
  #pragma message("posix")
  char *dir = (char*)calloc(PATH_MAX, sizeof(char));
  if (dir != nullptr) {
    char *tmp = realpath(argv, dir); 
    if (tmp != nullptr) ret = tmp; 
    free(dir);
  }
  #endif
  try {
    ret = fs::canonical(fs::path(ret)).replace_extension(".conf").string();
  } catch(...) {
    ret = "";
  }
  return ret;
}

int main(int, char** argv) {
  std::cout << GetConfigPath(argv[0]) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

При условии. что запускаемый процесс корректно заполняет `argv[0]`.

Онлайн пример для `POSIX` - [тут](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jXO9BSiI5QYkKSiR).

Comment: Вам еще не рассказали, что вы вроде умный, а не знаете, что в `argv[0]` - *"это то что передается в командную строку."*? :)

Comment: Каюсь, "дебаты" прочел уже позже. Ну что уж тут поделать. В `С++17` с `filesystem` хорошо подсуетились.

Comment: как и следовало ожидать - не работает

Comment: А в онлайн-компиляторе работает. А у вас что?

Comment: Добавил пример вывода под `Windows`. Собирал с помощью Mingw32 (g++ (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.1.0)

Comment: Эмм.. юзеру придется писать полный путь до программы? Ты серьезно щас?

Comment: В argv[0] система автоматом помещает название исполняемого файла с путем к нему. Юзеру нужно просто запустить исполняемый файл. А вот аргументы командной строки, если есть, ложатся в argv[1 и далее]. Разве так сложно проверить, поэксперементировать?

Comment: *как и следовало ожидать - не работает* Ага, это говорит о том, что вы таки не понимаете, что такое `argv[0]`, и как с ним работать... Я-то думал, что вы о крайне редком случае, когда надо очень постараться, чтоб обмануть компилятор, а вы просто не поняли, как ого работает...

Comment: @Harry я то знаю. И я наконец-то вас понял. Windows запускает программы "написанием в консоль" полного пути до программы. А у меня компилятор, мне не с ярлыка запускать.. А из консоли. По типу g++ main.cpp. И я уже решил свою проблему созданием переменной среды.

Comment: Рука-лицо :( Да почитай ты уже https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-language/arguments-to-main?view=vs-2019 . Ярлыки ... консоли тут не причем! Да хоть ты из CreateProcess будешь вызывать исполняемый файл (даже без указания полного пути, но исполняемый файл должен тогда быть в PATH) - все равно в argv[0] будет имя исполняемого файла с абсолютным путем.

Comment: @Majestio либо я не знаю почему у тебя так, либо я абсолютно не знаю что у тебя не так. У меня argv[0] это то как вызываем файл из консоли. Если полный путь писал - полный, относительный - относительный

Comment: В argv[0] система ничего не помещает автоматом. При создании процесса, что на Windows, что на Linux, можно свободно задавать содержимое argv[0].

Comment: В общем, я понял, что мой первоначальный код работает правильно во всех случаях, кроме одного. А именно, когда исполняемый модуль находится где-то в каталоге, прописанном в PATH, а вызывается из другого каталога без указания полного пути, только написанием имени исполняемого модуля. Исправляю данную ошибку, привожу иной вариант.

Comment: эмм.. Не только этот вариант не работает. Проще сказать, когда работает. А работает он только когда для запуска программы пишется полный путь.

Comment: Ну пусть так. Новый код работает нормально.